# Heroke deployment app crash keeps crashing

Tags: node.js, heroku

I know, I know, this may have been asked many times, but I just don't understand the error message. I'm not able to follow the error stack below. If you guys can help locating what is causing not being able launch my app will be greatly appreciated.

```
 db connected successfully
2017-01-19T03:34:27.564317+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/cover.jpg" host=xxxx.herokuapp.com request_id=xxx-55ed-476d-be16-78b88axxxx fwd="45.20.xxx.xxx" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=28ms status=200 bytes=108308
2017-01-19T03:34:27.566725+00:00 app[web.1]: GET /images/cover.jpg 200 10.252 ms - 108029
2017-01-19T03:34:29.588301+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-01-19T03:34:29.597382+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2017-01-19T03:34:29.475407+00:00 app[web.1]: events.js:160
2017-01-19T03:34:29.475422+00:00 app[web.1]:       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2017-01-19T03:34:29.475423+00:00 app[web.1]:       ^
2017-01-19T03:34:29.475424+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-01-19T03:34:29.475425+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: spawn compass ENOENT
2017-01-19T03:34:29.475426+00:00 app[web.1]:     at exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
2017-01-19T03:34:29.475427+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:182:32)
2017-01-19T03:34:29.475428+00:00 app[web.1]:     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:348:16)
2017-01-19T03:34:29.475428+00:00 app[web.1]:     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
2017-01-19T03:34:29.475429+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
2017-01-19T03:34:29.488804+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-01-19T03:34:29.496263+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-105-generic
2017-01-19T03:34:29.496491+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2017-01-19T03:34:29.496733+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v6.4.0
2017-01-19T03:34:29.496934+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
2017-01-19T03:34:29.497120+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2017-01-19T03:34:29.497271+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! xxxxx@1.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
2017-01-19T03:34:29.497396+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2017-01-19T03:34:29.497536+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have `compass` in your path hence the error

I'm not sure how it works with Heroku but on a normal machine, you can simply install it

```
$ gem update --system
$ gem install compass
```

You can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25091012/heroku-compass-buildpack-compass-fail) and heroku buildpack multi.

Comment: why do I need compass? I thought compass is just for when compiling the scss files

Comment: I have no idea but the error above looks like that. Can you post your code?

Comment: On my package.json file I had a packaged call "node-compass": "0.2.3", I commented out tried again. Still failing with same error. What code would you like to see? Is an entire nodejs app.

Comment: @JuanGonzales can you check if you require it somewhere in your code?

Comment: Thanks. I did had a "require(compass)" under my app.js not sure how it got there. Late nights makes your eye sight tired. Thanks again.